# Creating a splash page which has different background every time the app is opened

Tags: android

I am trying to create a splash page which shows different backgrounds every time it is opened.
I have used the following code to do that:

```
package com.example.asd;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Drawable back;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();

         int num=(int)Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6);
         switch(num)
         {
         case 1: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f1);
         break;
         case 2: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f2);
         break;
         case 3: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f3);
         break;
         case 4: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f4);
         break;
         case 5: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f5);
         break;
         case 6: back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f6);
         break;
         default:back=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.f5);
         break;
         }
         LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
         l1.setBackground(back);
         setContentView(l1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

When I try running this code the app crashes.Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting  `NullPointerException` because you are not calling `setContentView` before accessing current layout views. do it as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_id_in_activity_main);
l1.setBackground(back);
```

Also use `R.id.<view_id_in_xml>` instead of `R.layout.<layout_name_in_res_layout_dir>` to initialize any View from xml using id.

Comment: how do i get the layout_id_in_activity_main

Comment: @ganapathy : in `activity_main` you have LinearLayout ? then set any id for this layout to access in code as:  `android:id="@+id/linear_layout"`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because `findViewById` retuns `View` after `setContentView()`.

Change this line

```
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
```

into

```
LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
```

Based on OP requirement

add these lines to your code

```
    TextView textView=new TextView(this);
    textView.setText("setYour test");
    l1.addView(textView);
```

Comment: Thanks the application has started working :)
The only problem is that I have a text view in the activity_main. If I use the method that you have mentioned above then that text view is not appearing

Comment: @ganapathy checkout my edit and let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0):

replace these lines

```
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
         l1.setBackground(back);
         setContentView(l1);
```

as 
  pass layout id in setcontent view

```
setContentView(R.layout.main)   
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
l1.setBackground(back);
```

or

```
LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
l1.setBackground(back);
setContentView(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code from this

```
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
     l1.setBackground(back);
```

to

```
LinearLayout l1=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
     l1.setBackground(back);
```

and this will resolve your issue